# The ParseReact is not receiving data (error: this._subscriptions[name].dispose is not a function)

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs

I am using parse as my app back-end, but I am unable to receive data with the observe() method, although I'm sure that react is properly connect with parse, because I can mutate data with the ParseReact.mutation.

```
import React from 'react';
import Parse from 'parse';
import ParseReact from 'parse-react';

const pinRegister = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],

  observe() {
    return {
      pins: (new Parse.Query('Pin'))
  },
  render() {
    return {
      <ul>
       {this.data.pins.map(function(pin) {
        return <li>{pin}</li>;
       })}
      </ul>
    }
  }        
});
```

On the console I receive this message: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://mywsaddress:8080/parse' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response" and the this.data.pins gets undefined,I checked the data in parse-dashboard and the Pin class has the properly data.

Edit: I add the liveQuery on my parse server, and the socket error stopped, but I'm still unable to receive data, on chrome's console I get this: Uncaught TypeError: this._subscriptions[name].dispose is not a function, and this problem comes from this peace of code from parse-react:

```
_unsubscribe: function _unsubscribe() {
    for (var name in this._subscriptions) {
      this._subscriptions[name].dispose();
    }
    this._subscriptions = {};
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not included ParseReact.Mixin correctly. Replace "mixis" on "mixins".

```
mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but now it's telling me this: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://myWebServiceIp:8080/parse' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response", That was actually the initial problem, but now I figured out that I stopped receiving this websocket error because of this stupid type error.